# Windows project c++ simulate piano key with keyboard

Tags: c++, key, simulate

I need to simulate pressed piano keys with my keyboard, but I can't get it to work.
I can get sounds to play when I create the window(execute my code), but not when I press any keys. These sounds play automatically if I put them before the switch(message). Have I done something obviously wrong?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
HMIDIOUT hMidiOut;
int wmId, wmEvent;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;

// Open MIDI for output 
midiOutOpen(&hMidiOut, -1, 0, 0, 0); 
// Set instrument to 0 = Acoustic Grand Piano 
midiOutShortMsg(hMidiOut, DWORD(0x0C0 | 0 | (0 << 8) | (0 << 16))); 


switch (message)
{
case WM_KEYDOWN:
{
switch (wParam) {

case VK_LEFT:

    // Set instrument to 0 = Acoustic Grand Piano

    midiOutShortMsg (hMidiOut, DWORD(0x090 | 0 | (65<<8 ) | (64 << 16)));
    break;

    case 'S':
    midiOutShortMsg (hMidiOut, DWORD(0x090 | 0 | (62<<8 ) | (64 << 16)));   
    break;

    case 'D':
    midiOutShortMsg (hMidiOut, DWORD(0x090 | 0 | (64<<8 ) | (64 << 16)));
    break;

    case 'F':
    midiOutShortMsg (hMidiOut, DWORD(0x090 | 0 | (65<<8 ) | (64 << 16)));
    break;

    case 'G':
    midiOutShortMsg (hMidiOut, DWORD(0x090 | 0 | (67<<8 ) | (64 << 16)));
    break;

    case 'H':
    midiOutShortMsg (hMidiOut, DWORD(0x090 | 0 | (69<<8 ) | (64 << 16)));
    break;

    case 'J':
    midiOutShortMsg (hMidiOut, DWORD(0x090 | 0 | (71<<8 ) | (64 << 16)));
    break;

    case 'K':
    midiOutShortMsg (hMidiOut, DWORD(0x090 | 0 | (72<<8 ) | (64 << 16)));
    break;
}}
```

Comment: Do you really want to call `midiOutOpen` everytime your `WndProc` is called? That seems like something you'd do once when the application starts. Also, I don't see any call to `midiOutClose`. Both `midiOutOpen` and `midiOutShortMsg` return an `MMRESULT` which you should check to see if the call was successful, rather than just assuming that they were successful.

Comment: In the old days most keyboards could only reliably detect 3 to 4 simultaneously pressed keys. I suspect that's still so. It may be enough for playing simple piano tunes though.